# Proper way to type-hint undetermined (abstract) class attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, type-hinting

I created an abstract class `Animal` for simillar classes (`Cat, Dog, Horse ...`) sharing simillar methods.

Also, I want to use the class `Animal` as an indicator of their common attributes(`id, name, weight, ...`) and their types as code below, but it looks so ugly to me.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Optional


class Animal(ABC):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.id: Optional(int) = None
        self.name: Optional(str) = None
        self.weight: Optional(float) = None
        self.height: Optional(float) = None
        self.age: Optional(int) = None
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def cry(self) -> None:
        pass
```

Should I type hint all attributes as Optional, since their values are not determined (so I initialized them with `None`) in abstract class `Animal`? Are there any better way to type-hint undetermined class attributes?

Comment: you can use Union for typing if you expect to get None and other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to say that any subclass of `Animal` should have the attributes `id`, `name`, etc., but not providing any defaults (which I assume is why you assigned them `None`), then you can declare them using class attribute annotations:

```
class Animal(ABC):
    id: int
    name: str
    weight: float
    height: float
    age: int

    @abstractmethod
    def cry(self) -> None:
        ....
```

Note that this will not provide you with *guarantees* that all subclasses must have these attributes. It's merely a hint to the programmer and the IDE & typechecker, and in most cases this will suffice.

If you wish to be certain, you can define them as abstract properties, although it would be quite verbose:

```
class Animal(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def name(self) -> str:
        ...

# Subclasses can implement that as a simple class attribute...
class Cat(Animal):
    name = "cat"

# ... or as a proper property.
class Dog(Animal):
    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.breed} dog"
```